# Edit Data for Store View UI component is not displaying with selected value

Tags: uicomponent, store-view, magento2.4.4, multiselect, data-provider

I have created a custom module and have used UI component to display store view field in Form page.

> **I am facing this issue only in Production Mode.**

When I open the Edit form page the Store View UI component does not show with selected value.
I checked the Data Provider class with logs and data is getting loaded.

**Store View Ui Component Screenshot**
[image: Store View UI Component]

**Database Screenshot**
[image: Database Screenshot]

**Data Provide Class:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\HomePage\Model;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Vendor\HomePage\Model\ResourceModel\DynamicHomePageBlock\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
/**
 * @var array
 */
public $loadedData;
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    protected CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    protected RequestInterface $request,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
}

/**
 * Get Data function
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getData()
{
    $this->logger->info('Data Provider: Get Data:');

    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        // Debug : Row 838
        $this->logger->info(__('Data:ISSET:'), $this->loadedData['838']);
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $dynamicCollection) {
        $data = $dynamicCollection->getData();
        $this->loadedData[$dynamicCollection->getId()] = $data;
    }
    // Debug : Row 838
    $this->logger->info(__('Data'), $this->loadedData['838']);

    return $this->loadedData;
}

/**
 * Get Meta function
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getMeta()
{
    $meta = parent::getMeta();
    return $meta;
}
}
```

**Ui Component**

```
<field name="store_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to correct in DataProvider.php file

Need to return the value in array format for the multiselect field.

```
[id] => 3
[profile_code] => bnm
[in_profile_products] => 
// Return in Array 
[store_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )
// Return in Array
[form_key] => XVHZNnwpvU0Kwvvn
```

Below is the Modified getData() function of DataProvider.php file

```
    /**
 * Get Data function
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getData()
{
    $this->logger->info('Data Provider: Get Data:');

    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        // Debug : Row 838
        $this->logger->info(__('Data:ISSET:'), $this->loadedData['838']);
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $dynamicCollection) {
        $data = $dynamicCollection->getData();

        // Here I convert the value to array
        $data['store_id'] = [0 => $data['store_id']];
        // Here I convert the value to array

        $this->loadedData[$dynamicCollection->getId()] = $data;
    }
    // Debug : Row 838
    $this->logger->info(__('Data'), $this->loadedData['838']);

    return $this->loadedData;
}
```